# How to define return type of arrow function?

Tags: typescript

While creating a CDK construct, I want to be able to enforce that exactly-one of a set of properties is set*:

```js
export interface MyConstructProps {
  function?: Function, // Exactly-one of this or pathToAssetCode must be set
  pathToAssetCode?: string, // Exactly-one of this or function must be set
  ...
  [key: string]: any
}

export class MyConstruct extends cdk.Construct {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: MyConstructProps) {
    super(scope, id);
    
    const exactlyOneProperties = ['function', 'pathToAssetCode']
    assert(
      exactlyOneProperties
        .map((propertyName) => (props[propertyName] == undefined) ? 0 : 1)
        .reduce((a: number, b: number) => a+b) == 1,
      `Exactly one of the properties ${exactlyOneProperties} must be present`)

    let function;
    if (props.function == undefined) {
      function = new Function(this, 'function', {
        code: new AssetCode(props.pathToAssetCode),
        ...
      });
    } else {
      function = props.function;
    }

    ...

  }
}
```

However, this gives a red underline under the `a+b`, with the message `TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1 | 0'.`. Why is Typescript inferring that the return value of the sum of two `number`s (which *happen* to be constrained to be `1|0` - but I've explicitly "widened" the type-signature of the reducing function to be `number`) must be `1|0` - and how do I explicitly tell it that I *want* the return type of my reducing function to be `number`?

I tried `.reduce((a, b): number => {return a+b}) == 1`, but that gave `TS2345: Argument of type '(a: 1 | 0, b: 1 | 0) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: 1 | 0, currentValue: 1 | 0, currentIndex: number, array: (1 | 0)[]) => 1 | 0'.   Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1 | 0'.` - which looks to me like there is a different signature of `reduce` being invoked, not the single-parameter function-accepting one I'm aiming for.

---

* yes, I know that I could do that by declaring `function: Function | string` as the property's type-signature, but that name doesn't fit for the "path to" case, and naming it `functionOrPathToFunctionCode` feels cumbersome. I'm also aware that I could have done this exactly-one-defined check with a few sequential `if-else` statements - but I want to learn how the language works!

Comment: `(a === 1 || b === 1) ? 1 : 0` - return this instead.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not legal to add `1|0` to `1|0`? EDIT: also I'm pretty sure that doesn't have the same functionality, if both a and b are 1 it will still return 1, not 2 as it should.

Comment: `.reduce((a: number, b: number) => a+b, 0 as number) == 1,` <- would this work for you?

Comment: Indeed, that got rid of the red underline - in fact, the type-hints for the parameters weren't necessary, it worked with just `.reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0 as number) `. Could you tell me (or give me some tips on what to Google to understand) why that fixed it? I'd already tried `.reduce((a, b) => a+b as number)` which gave the same `Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1|0'` error.

Comment: Just mouse hover the `reduce` to see the inferred type, it clarifies why `0 as number` is necessary.

Comment: Interesting. I see 2 type-signatures, and I assume the relevant one (since the other only deals in a single type) is `reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U`. So it's not possible to reduce over an array of `0|1`s to produce a `number` - I need to explicitly provide a `number` starting value. I guess that makes sense (in the absence of [Upper Bounds](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-upper-bound/), etc.) - the output of `reduce` must be precisely the same type as the first argument for the next iteration. Thanks!